# Wordpress Menu with data scroll

Tags: wordpress, menu

I want to create below menu in wordpress

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a data-scroll href="#intro">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll href="#aboutIntro">About</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll href="#featured-works">Services</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll href="#profile">Company Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll href="#contactContent">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a data-scroll href="#contactIntro">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have below code for creating menu...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-menu', 'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 'theme_location'  => 'primary') ); ?>
```

Don't know how to bring `data-scroll` in this `<li>` anchor...??

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a custom Nav Walker for that, here is one pre-built for adding a custom attribute to anchors: [Handle custom anchor attributes with WordPress wp_nav_menu()](https://gist.github.com/gxela/6333248)

You can also use jQuery to add anchors like below:

```
jQuery('ul.nav a').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).attr('data-scroll', '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class) Class. Edit the HTML as needed.

Also make sure you edit the template which calls the `wp_nav_menu` function (mostly the `header.php` file) and add the `walker` parameter to it.